# What is the difference between RadSearchBox and RadComboBox?

Tags: telerik, radcombobox

What is the difference between the Telerik RadSearchBox and RadComboBox controls?  I've googled and searched here and I can't seem to find information about the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one (restaurant) table with three column (ID,ItemCategory,ItemName). Suppose you have 6 Item under Vegetarian Category and 4 item under Non-vegetarian category.

[Radcombobox](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) : This will bind all the 10 items in the radcombobox.

[RadSearchBox](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/searchbox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) : This controls contain one DropDownList and Textbox. In dropdown It will bind ItemCategory
field value. if you select Vegetarian category from dropdown list and if you will type anything in textbox than it will shows maximum 6 items, which has Vegetarian category.

Let me know if any concern.